# How do I find a supplied field in jira-python

Tags: python, jira

I have a class which does all tasks like lookup PR, etc.

I have a method there:

```
class myJiraClass:    
    def return_supplied_field(self, issue, field_name):
        """ Essentially I need to return issue.fields.field_name here """

test = myJiraClass();    
issue = test.find_issue("IL-1010")
summary = test.return_supplied_field(issue, "summary")
print summary
```

How do I do this?

I want this function to simply return the field value like:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`getattr()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) to dynamically look up attributes:

```
def return_supplied_field(self, issue, field_name):
    """ Essentially I need to return issue.fields.field_name here """
    return getattr(issue.fields, field_name)
```

Comment: And hasattr() can be used to check the field_name exists there as expected